# How can I let two classes communicate with each other the best in C++

Tags: c++

What I have now 2 Classes, of which one has the other, ClassB is a part of ClassA, I thought of this abstract example to show how the relation is.

```
//-----------car.cpp
#include "engine.cpp"

class Car{
   Engine engine;
   ErrorLight errorLight;

   //in other languages I would here pass the method engineReportsError 
   //in this function
   engine.startEngine(); 

void engineReportsError(errorId){
   errorLight.showEngineError(errorId);
{
};

//-----------engine.cpp

class Engine{
void run(){
   //...
   if(error){
       //report error to Car without returning the function
   }
}
};
```

I am just now learning C++ as a new language but am not new to programming, so the problem I have is the engine telling the car that something isn't workig without the engine returning the function but from within the run() tell the Car about the occured error. I am almost sure that I did something wrong about the example above, and almost even more sure that there is a different solution to this problem, but what I really need is this method to just tell the car.

Things I tried before:

Callbacks => of what i read callbacks apparently don't work with member functions, and making the function static also won't work because i need to access other things in this class, because from this function i need to access other things the car has which I, if i understood correctly, cannot read/change inside the static

Includes  => I tried including the car into the engine but for one I do not think a car having a reference to an Engine and the engine to the same car is a good solution, if even possible (wouldn't there be an infinte loop of referencing each other?)

Comment: In this case you could just check the state of the engine after `engine.startEngine();`. Also, member functions can be callbacks, but they must be called through a reference to their owning object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callback should work, but you have to pass also the custom data...

We are in C++, you can use `std::function` to resolve all those issue:

```
class Car{
   Engine engine;
   ErrorLight errorLight;

   Car() {
       engine.startEngine(
           [this](const std::string& msg){
               return this->engineReportsError(msg);
           }); 
   }
   Car(const Car&) = delete;
   Car& operator=(const Car&) = delete;

   bool engineReportsError(const std::string& errorId){
      return errorLight.showEngineError(errorId);
   }
};
//-----------engine.cpp

class Engine{

    void startEngine(std::function<bool(const std::string&)> report) {
        // ...
        reportError = report;
    }

    void run(){
       //...
       if (error){
           auto res = reportError("Oh no!!!");
           // ...
       }
    }

    std::function<bool(const std::string&)> reportError;
};
```

Should probably go in constructor instead of `startEngine`.

And when capturing `this`, we have to care about copy/move.

Comment: This works, thank you very much! I forgot to add that the engineReportsError needs to return something back to the engine, how would that be implemented?

Comment: You have to change the lambda and std::function accordingly. change to return bool on my side.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, just keep a pointer to Car inside Engine class, and then you can use it to call a public function defined in Car.

```
class Engine;   //forward declaration

class Car {
private:
    Engine* engine;
public:
    Car(Engine* e) : engine(e) {}
    void error() {};
};

class Engine {
private:
    Car* carPtr;
public:
    Engine() : carPtr(nullptr) {};
    void setIntoCar(Car* car) {
        carPtr = car;
    }
    void foo() {
        carPtr->error();    //calls a function from Car class
    }
};

int main() {
    Engine engine;
    Car car(&engine);
    engine.setIntoCar(&car);

}
```

Comment: is it good practice to have a pointer to the car in the engine?

Comment: It might be convenient, but increases the coupling. With that coupling, to test engine, you need a Car :-/ You can take a `IErrorReporter` interface instead.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my code a bit so you can compile it and develop further. If you need to refer from Engine to its Car, and vice versa, then you need pointers, and there's nothing bad about it. Moreover, how can you initialize one of them if it needs the other one already been initialized?

Comment: @Hack06: `engine.setIntoCar(&car);` can go in Car constructor.

Comment: No. it works like this: you build your engine so that you know it will be inserted into a car (unknown at that moment). Then you build your car, by first building it's frame, and then adding the ready engine into it. And finally, you tell the engine on which car it is, so each of them can communicate with each other onwards.

Comment: @Hack06: When don't you want `Car car(&engine);
    engine.setIntoCar(&car);`? IMO, `Car car(&engine);` already means that engine is in car.

Comment: ```Car car(&engine);``` means add the engine into car and let the car know its engine, while ```engine.setIntoCar(&car);``` means link the engine to the same car in which you've just added it in the previous step.